# Use $http in a controller constructor without obtaining it as a parameter

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to create a controller for this karma test (practicing TDD, I should not change the test):

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector, $rootScope) {
// Set up the mock http service responses
$httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
$http = $injector.get('$http');

// backend definition common for all tests
apiCertificatesServerHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/certificates/1')
    .respond({"id":1,"name":"example.com","issuer":"Cert Corp.","expires":1469565860612});

// The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
var $rootParams = $injector.get('$rootParams');

createController = function() {
return $controller('CertificateController', {'$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope': $rootScope.$new() '$routeParams': {id: 1}});
};
}));
```

and then:

```
it('should fetch certificate', function() {
$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/certificates/1');
var vm = createController();
$httpBackend.flush();
expect(vm.data).toEqual({"id":1,"name":"example.com","issuer":"Cert Corp.","expires":1469565860612});
});
```

The only way to obtain the info via GET request in the controller, (that I can think of), is obtaining $http in the constructor. But this is not what the test expects. Here is my solution, which is not ok according to the test:

```
function CertificateController($http, $routeParams) {
    var vm = this;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/certificates/' + $routeParams.id
        }).then(function (certificate) { ...
```

Can you advice me how to write the controller in order the test to pass? If I instantiate it only with $rootScope and $scope, how to obtain the $http obj that I need? Can you advice me how can I get a reference to the $http parameter in this case?

Comment: I don't understand your question/problem? Have you tried running the test? What happens? What's the problem? Why do you expect vm.data to exist before you flush $httpBackend, especially given you haven't told *what* to return as a response to the request? Also, why do you pass $rootScope and $scope when creating the controller, since those aren't needed by the controller?

Comment: Hi JB, Thank you for your reply!  "especially given you haven't told what to return as a response to the request?" - I just didn't paste the complete test. Here it is: apiCertificatesServerHandler = $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/certificates/1')
        .respond({"id":1,"name":"example.com","issuer":"Cert Corp.","expires":""});    Actually, this is an application with provided tests, and I am required to implement it in a way that the test pass. I am wondering how to implement the controller, using the provided $rootScope and $scope and NOT providing $http as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Why wouldn't you pass $http as a constructor parameter? That's the correct way to inject a service. Again, what happens when you run the test? You seem to think that the problem is that the constructor takes $http as argument, but that is not the case. Angular **will** pass $http to the constructor, even though the test doesn't pass it in createController().

Comment: I don't pass the $http, because the requirement for my code is to match the test exactly - I am provided the test as it is - without passing the $http. I tried to run the test without providing $http parameter from the test, but expecting it in the controller, and I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string". It is possible that I didn't understand your reply? You say that the framework will pass the $http object anyway. Should I obtain it using dependency injection inside the constructor (something like injector.get...?) Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your syntax error has nothing to do with $http. $controller() creates and injects the controller. The second argument is used to provide values for the arguments that are not services, or that must replace the "normal" service that it would otherwise inject. Just keep $http as an argument of your CertificateController. The test will pass with that argument. And read the documentation of $controller: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller. See how $log is injected even though the locals argument is an empty object.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was looking at a totally wrong place, thinking that the parameters provided are wrong. The documentation that you gave me above was very helpful, now I understand how this works. Turns out, that I am missing a comma in the test code which caused the syntax error.